# Counting representations of $k[x,y]$ when $k$ is finite

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, commuting-variety

$\newcommand{\GFq}{\mathbf F_q}$
Let $r_n(q)$ denote the number of isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional modules of the $\GFq$-algebra $\GFq[x,y]$. Is it known whether there exists a polynomial $p_n(t)$ (with say, integer coefficients) such that $r_n(q) = p_n(q)$ for all prime powers $q$?

Here are the values that I know (see [arXiv:1212.6157v2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6157v2)):

- $r_1(q) = q^2$
- $r_2(q) = q^4 + q^3 + q^2$
- $r_3(q) = q^6 + q^5 + 2q^4 + q^3 + 2q^2$
- $r_4(q) = q^8 + q^7 + 3q^6 + 3q^5 + 5q^4 + 3q^3 + 3q^2$

Note: for the free algebra $\GFq\langle x, y\rangle$ this is well known, since it is the number of $n$-dimensional representations of the quiver with one vertex and two loops. In fact, it is also known now that this polynomial has non-negative integer coefficients (this follows from the work of [Mozgovoy](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2100) or [Hausel, Letellier and Rodriguez-Villegas](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2375)).

Answer (score 14):

The number you seek is closely related to the number of commuting pairs of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbf{F}_q$. This is a polynomial and the formula was first given by Feit and Fine in a 1960 Duke paper. The stack of $\mathbf{F}_q[x,y]$ modules is the stack quotient of the commuting variety

$$C(n) = \{(A,B)\in End(\mathbf{F}_q^n)^2 : [A,B]=0\}$$

by $Gl(n)$ acting by conjugation. The number you have asked for is the number of points in the coarse space of this stack. I don't know much about that number, but the "stacky" number of points is much better behaved --- in other words, instead of counting modules, you should be counting modules by 1 over the number of automorphisms of the module. That number is equal to the number of commuting pairs of matrices over $\mathbf{F}_q$ divided by the number of elements in $Gl(n,\mathbf{F}_q)$. The generating function of that number has a nice product expansion:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|C(n)|}{|Gl(n)|} t^n = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-q^{2-m}t^k)^{-1}$$

This is in Feit and Fine's paper or you can find a more modern motivic derivation of this in my paper with Morrison. http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5864

Comment: If the stack is Deligne-Mumford, the number of $\mathbf F_q$-points is the same for the stack and the coarse space. Is this true here?

Comment: No, the stack is not DM. For example the trivial module of length n (corresponding to the 0 matrices in the commuting variety) has the full $Gl(n)$ as its automorphism group.

Comment: The number is seek is not however, the number of pairs of commuting matrices. It is the number of *simulateneous similarity classes of pairs of commuting matrices*.

Comment: Yes, that's why he's dividing by $GL(n)$ acting by conjugation!

Comment: But the arxiv preprint looks very interesting. Thanks, @JimBryan for that.

Comment: @Amritanshu : Just to clarify, the number you are asking for is $|C(n)/Gl(n)|$, which is the number of isomorphism classes of modules, which is the cardinality of the coarse moduli space of the stack $[C(n)/Gl(n)]$. The number that is given by the above formula is $|C(n)|/|Gl(n)|$, which is the number of isomorphism classes of modules counted by the reciprocal number of automorphisms, which is (in some sense) the cardinality of the stack $[C(n)/Gl(n)]$. The stack is often better behaved than its coarse space so maybe your original question doesn't have a good answer, but I don't know.

Comment: @JimBryan I feel that the original question should have a very nice answer because I could do explicit calculations for $n\leq 4$ (see my edit).

Comment: You might want to edit your question so that the tags "commuting variety" and/or "algebraic geometry" appear. The question is really about the class of the coarse space $C(n)/Gl(n)$ in the Grothendieck group of varieties --- there is a lemma of Katz which says that a class in the Grothendieck group will be a polynomial in $[\mathbb{A}^1]$ iff the point count over $\mathbf{F}_q$ is polynomial in $q$. So you should look for an affine paving of $C(n)/Gl(n)$, i.e. a stratification where the strata are all affine spaces. You could find this over $\mathbb{C}$ and that would suffice.

Comment: It might well be easier (and good enough) to pave by tori instead of affine spaces. But anyway, this begins to sound too much like the wild problem of classifying representations of $k[x,y]$. I doubt you're going to get results for general $n$.

Comment: I kind of agree with Allen's assessment. I did look at what would happen if you apply the power structure methods of my paper with Morrison to this problem and it boils down to computing the class of $Stab_{J_{\lambda}}(Gl(n))/Stab_{J_\lambda}(Gl(n))$ in the Grothendieck group. Here $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$ and $J_\lambda$ is the nilpotent matrix in Jordan form with blocks of size $\lambda_i$, and $Stab_{J_\lambda}(Gl(n))$ is the stabilizer of $J_\lambda$ in $Gl(n)$ acting on itself by conjugation. The class of the stack quotient is just 1, but the class of the

Comment: orbit space will be tricky to figure out. Still, maybe one could at least show it is paved by affines (or tori).

Comment: @JimBryan The difficulty here is finding a uniform way to deal with all $\lambda$ in a uniform manner.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that $r_n(1)$ is the middle coefficient of $(1+x+x^2)^n$ for $1\leq n\leq 4$?

Comment: @RichardStanley I don't know, but here is another interesting observation: if $r_{n,k}$ is the number of iso classes of $n$-dimensional $\mathbf F_q[x_1,\dotsc,x_k]$-modules, then $r_{2,k} = q^k\binom{k+1}1_q$ and $r_{3,k} = q^k[\binom{k+2}2_q + \binom k2_q]$.